# How to find a value in binary expression tree?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

Given a tree for example like:

[image]

How can I let's say find the value `3` (it doesn't matter which value of `3`, but after one is found the search should conclude) in that tree and maybe change it to `7` or some other number, but after that stop traversing the tree? All of the algorithms I found online will always traverse the whole tree or when they search for a specific value then it's for a BST, which doesn't apply here. I cannot provide a code sample as I don't know where to start with this problem.

```
class Node {

    String value;
    Node left, right;

    Node(String item) {
        value = item;
        left = right = null;
    }

    boolean isLeaf() {
        return (left == null) && (right == null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which 3 do you want to modify?

Comment: The first one the search algorithm finds, it doesn't matter which one it is, but after one of them is modified, the algorithm i.e. the search should stop.

Comment: So if you want to find a value and change it to another value and then exit, why can't you adapt a traversal algorithm to just do that?

Comment: You can use a DFS on the tree until you find the number you are searching for, modify it and then prune your recursive calls from there on.

Comment: @nellex I will try thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need an algorithm to find a specific node based on its value. This can easily be done by traversing the tree in pre-order, in-order or post-order (see [Tree Traversal on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), especially [Implementation of Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal?oldformat=true#Depth-first_search_2)). This algorithm returns from recursion if the item has been found:

```
Node findNode(Node root, String value) {
    if (root == null) return null; // no such node
    if (value.equals(root.getValue())) return root; // the node itself contains the value

    Node n = findNode(root.getLeft(), value); // search left sub-tree
    if (n != null) return n; // we've found it in the left sub-tree

    return findNode(root.getRight(), value); // search right sub-tree
}
```

After that, it is easy to exchange a value in the tree:

```
void exchange(Node root, String value, String newValue) {
    Node n = findNode(root, value);
    n.setValue(newValue);
}
```

Of course you can also traverse the tree iteratively, but if you don't have very huge trees, there is no reason to *not* use the simpler recursive approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you want, you will always have to start traversing your tree from the root element (I am assuming you have access to the root initially) in a sequential manner (like in BFS or DFS). Since your tree isn't a BST (or a tree having some special relations between the nodes), there's no way we can search for a particular node any faster than a normal sequential search over all the nodes.

Sample BFS pseudo-code;

```
Initialize Queue q;
q.add(root);

while(q is not empty){
    Node node = q.pop();

    if(Node equal to 3){ // or any value you want
        node.val = 7;
        return;
    }

    if(node.left!=null){q.add(node.left);}
    if(node.right!=null){q.add(node.right);}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be faster it should just stop the search after I find one element that is equal to the search key.

Comment: @мајдејсаремех, Oh I thought you needed to do it in time-complexity less than O(N). My bad :) . I added pseudo-code for BFS